# One app in Django is enough for whole website?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm new to Django framework and currently working on an ecommerce website. Not sure what would be better, when creating new project and new app in Django, does a single app is enough and fine for whole website functionally(all HTML pages, user login/registration etc) or should I use separate apps in my project?

Answer (score 2):

one app for one purpose.

don't describe your app with 'and'.

like: my_app_name' to manage students and exams.

just create 'students' app to manage students and 'exams' to manage exams

Answer (score 2):

According to the great book on django 'Two scoops of django' we should create an app for only one purpose. If the work of an app is beyond a topic we should create another one.

So I think you should create separate apps for various tasks of your web-application like:

accounts : app for user model

products : app for product model

orders : app for managing orders

payments : app for the order payments

...
and many more.

Answer (score 0):

As far I have used Django in my profession about four years, I think Django and python is comprehensive kit for building e-commerce web app.

Comment: You wouldn't recommend Django for an e-commerce? if not, which backend framework is suggested? I don't mind the language (JavaScript, Python, PHP or others)